# Rails: Update loan amount with amount paid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, models, controllers

I am pretty new to rails and I wrote a little app that keeps track of loans.  There is a User model and a Loan model and I have it worked out to track who loaned who money, etc.

I am trying to write a new feature that would keep track of payment but I am unsure where I should put it.  This feature would update the database value of loan amount with a new value.  Would this feature be a part of the Loan class, would it be a new controller that can access the loans / users model?

My apologies if this question is overly vague, I can supply more info is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a method in the Loan model `make_payment(amount)` and reduce the amount from the total loan amount.

I would advice you to maintain a log of payments in order to keep track of them later. Create a `Payment` model that belongs to the `Loan` model.

Comment: You should definitely at least separate the original amount of the loan from the balance!

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure if I needed a seperate controller.  This solution is much simpler (especially becasue this is for personal use, not intended for market).

Comment: In order to update the loan amount from the web, would I need to use a patch request?

Answer (score 1):

The common scenario when you take a loan for a non-trivial amount is that you get a payment plan which is to be payed in number of instalments.

Each instalment can be payed by multiple payments.

So lets have a look at what the models would look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :loans
  has_many :instalments, through: :loans
  has_many :payments, through: :loans
end

# [int, foreign_key, index] user_id
# [float] total_amount - does not change!
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :instalments
  has_many :payments
end

# [int, foreign_key, index] loan_id
# [float] total_due
# [float] payed
# [datetime] due_date
class Instalment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loan  
  has_one :user, through: :loan
  has_many :payments
end

# [int, foreign_key, index] instalment_id
# [float] amount
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instalment
  has_one :loan, through: :instalment
  has_one :user, through: :loan
end
```

This might seem over complicated but is actually just enough to have some sort of financial accountability. We can keep track of how much the user is supposed to pay per month - and which payments are linked to a specific instalment. If you actually want to use this app for real you are very likely to encounter more legal accountability requirements (unless you are aiming for the Swiss market).

Lets talk a bit about the application flow here:

- When we create a loan we would create a number of instalments which the user is obliged to pay.
- Each time the user pays a instalment we set up a hook to update the payed amount on the instalment.
- We also need to periodically check if the user has payed their instalments on time.

Notice that in this domain model we don't update the amount on the Loan after creation - it's simply a record of the original amount they borrowed (remember that for accounting purposes you should always keep data).

Instead of we have to figure out how is remaining on a loan we would sum the `instalments.payed` column:

```
# [int, foreign_key, index] user_id
# [float] total_amount - does not change!
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :instalments
  has_many :payments

  def payed
    installments.sum(:payed)
  end 

  def amount_due
    total_amount - installments.sum(:payed)
  end
end
```

This is the kind of routes you will be needing:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
  resources :loans
end

resources :loans, only: [], shallow: true do
  resources :instalments
end

resources :instalments, only: [], shallow: true do
  resources :payments
end
```

---

`$ rake routes`

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
            user_loans GET    /users/:user_id/loans(.:format)                    loans#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/loans(.:format)                    loans#create
         new_user_loan GET    /users/:user_id/loans/new(.:format)                loans#new
             edit_loan GET    /loans/:id/edit(.:format)                          loans#edit
                  loan GET    /loans/:id(.:format)                               loans#show
                       PATCH  /loans/:id(.:format)                               loans#update
                       PUT    /loans/:id(.:format)                               loans#update
                       DELETE /loans/:id(.:format)                               loans#destroy
      loan_instalments GET    /loans/:loan_id/instalments(.:format)              instalments#index
                       POST   /loans/:loan_id/instalments(.:format)              instalments#create
   new_loan_instalment GET    /loans/:loan_id/instalments/new(.:format)          instalments#new
       edit_instalment GET    /instalments/:id/edit(.:format)                    instalments#edit
            instalment GET    /instalments/:id(.:format)                         instalments#show
                       PATCH  /instalments/:id(.:format)                         instalments#update
                       PUT    /instalments/:id(.:format)                         instalments#update
                       DELETE /instalments/:id(.:format)                         instalments#destroy
   instalment_payments GET    /instalments/:instalment_id/payments(.:format)     payments#index
                       POST   /instalments/:instalment_id/payments(.:format)     payments#create
new_instalment_payment GET    /instalments/:instalment_id/payments/new(.:format) payments#new
          edit_payment GET    /payments/:id/edit(.:format)                       payments#edit
               payment GET    /payments/:id(.:format)                            payments#show
                       PATCH  /payments/:id(.:format)                            payments#update
                       PUT    /payments/:id(.:format)                            payments#update
                       DELETE /payments/:id(.:format)                            payments#destroy
```

Comment: I appreciate how thorough this response is and the only reason I did not select it is because for my purposes, I do not need something so developed.  That being said, I hope this response will help other understand how associations work in rails!